# Are police in Western European countries right-wing or left-wing?

Tags: europe, police

In America, the police have a reputation for being politically conservative. One rarely sees clashes between conservative demonstrators and police.

In Europe, though, there seem to be lots of clashes between anti-lockdown (presumably conservative) and (in France) yellow vests movement protestors and police? Is this because police in Western Europe skew left?

Comment: I'm not sure why some people are insisting to close this question, but I vote to leave it open. I think it's a legitimate question.

Comment: The current question is ambiguous on whether the police institution or the individual policemen are biased.
@divibisan said in a comment of one of the answer : "[In the US, police are three times as likely to use force against leftwing protesters](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/jan/13/us-police-use-of-force-protests-black-lives-matter-far-right). So the question is, then, whether a similar pattern exists in Europe?"
Which I feel is a more appropriate question which could be answered.

Comment: @Simon I do think this question would be clearer if the title was "Do police in Western Europe show a bias in their interaction towards left-wing or right-wing demonstrators?"

Comment: Or if it clarified whether the question is about that or about the actual individual views of police officers, which is what most of the answers seem to be about and what the title suggests.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say either anti-lockdown or yellow vest protestors are all right-wing. In the US, anti-lockdown was closely correlated with Trump support, but there are also a lot of people on the eccentric fringe of environmentalism or dissident leftist (e.g. Piers Corbyn in the UK) who are conspiracy-minded and anti-lockdown.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not an easy question to answer, because it is hard to find unbiased reporting or studies on it.

@tim has given a good answer, I would like to add a different perspective:

When you check not the media, whose main interest is the generation of headlines, but the extremist groups whose main interest is self-defense against the police, you find that both left and right consider the police their enemy. I don't think I need to detail what the Antifa thinks about cops. But I have as well seen pamphlets circulating in right-wing circles with advise on how to act when police arrest or question you, and I could re-print them with minimal changes and give them to Antifa activists and they'd think their people wrote those.

If both the left- and right-wing outliers consider the police to be on the other side, then it follows that the police is on neither extreme. Which stands to reason given that "the police" is a rather large force with many different people in it.

Looking at the political spectrum and what the terms stand for, it's clear that "law and order" are more naturally associated with the right, so it is no surprise that studies find policemen more right leaning. That does not necessarily translate to right-wing opinions on questions such as immigration, employee laws, economic principles, healthcare, etc. etc.

The clashes you see are most easily explained by viewing the police as the defenders of the *status quo* and the current politics of the country, no matter what that is. When left-wing activists protest for better social support, they will clash with the police. When right-wing activists protest against immigration, they will clash with the police. And when Corona-tired conspiracy theorists protest the lockdown, they will clash with the police. Heck, if lunatics were to protest against the government keeping aliens from Jupiter prisoner in their secret vaults, they would clash with the police - and that doesn't mean the police is pro-imprisoning-aliens.

Comment: This is a better and more balanced answer, but it runs into the common sematics problem. You correctly note that police is (almost by definition) _conservative_, but conservative is NOT right. Conservative is just conservative. In the ex-communist countries of the 90s, "conservatives" were communists (yes, they were actually called that). _Individual liberty_ is the inherent right concept, not conservatism or "law and order".

Comment: @Zeus: Conservative is right. I would expect the police in England lean heavily towards the tories. Having said that, that is still to the left of the US right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120986/discussion-between-zeus-and-mozibur-ullah).

Comment: The problem with this answer is that, yes, the police will clash with any set of protesters, but the nature of their response, and it’s level of violence, varies greatly. In the US, [police are three times as likely to use force against leftwing protesters](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/jan/13/us-police-use-of-force-protests-black-lives-matter-far-right). So the question is, then, whether a similar pattern exists in Europe?

Comment: The rightward leanings of police forces don't >necessarily< translate to right-wing opinions on immigration etc., but the answer about French surveys shows that there is a pretty strong correlation (LePen is famous particularly for being virulently nationalist and anti-immigrant).

Comment: "If both the left- and right-wing outliers consider the police to be on the other side, then it follows that the police is on neither extreme." - no it doesn't, this is completely specious reasoning. As you say further on, police are defenders of the status quo - that's pretty close to a definition of conservatism.

Comment: @divibisan That provides no evidence at all for the police being left or right any more than "the police are more likely to use violence against armed bank robbers" is evidence that the police are bankers. Leftist protests are simply more likely to be violent (in the current-day, U.S., that is.) _A lot_ more likely. Last year alone, there were dozens of left-wing protests in which people were killed by the protesters (and 2 where someone was killed by police.) On the right, as far as I know, there were zero (though there was unfortunately the obvious one at the beginning of this year.)

Comment: I have downvoted this answer, because (1) it offers no sources, and (2) it's factually incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, it’s not a good look that this answer, that has not data, evidence, or sources and doesn’t even _mention_ Europe was accepted. It really does nothing to answer the question

Comment: Erm, can you provide any evidence right-wingers think police are on the other side? Aside from attacking them at the Capitol, I know of no serious conservative thinker (lol) that seriously considers the police to be left-wing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121086/discussion-on-answer-by-tom-are-police-in-western-european-countries-right-wing).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I never said police are left-wing. I said that extremists on boths sides see the police not as allies, but as enemies.

Answer (score 84):

Speaking for Germany, officially they are bound to be neutral. Practically, they lean (heavily) right.

Looking at the anti-lockdown protests (which are indeed right to far-right), the police has been very hands-off compared to left-wing demonstrations.

In recent years, [many cases](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten/politik/rechtsextremismus-polizei-lagebericht-100.html) of far-right extremist networks inside the police have been discovered (but as of yet no far-left networks).

The largest police union ([GdP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gewerkschaft_der_Polizei)) is center-right, though even they see that many [police officers are sympathetic](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2019-06/rechtspopulismus-bundespolizei-afd-gewerkschaft-gdp) to right-wing nationalism. The second-largest police union ([DPolG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Polizeigewerkschaft)) is [hard right](https://taz.de/Polizei-kritisiert-Polizisten/!5694351/). There isn't any left-wing union.

[Scientific analyses](https://www.bpb.de/apuz/291189/polizei-und-rechtsextremismus) have shown that right-wing ideology is not an issue of a individual cases, but a structural problem in the police. Racial profiling is prevalent and right-wing extremism is under-estimated and institutional racism is negatively affecting police work (see e.g. [NSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Socialist_Underground)).

Comment: I'd wager that the explanation for this could be that working as police officer is generally not as appealing to the average liberal-left person as it is to the average authoritarian-right person.

Comment: The studies don't really talk about the "average [X/Y]-leaning person", though. They talk about extremist networks and largely individual cases. If you were studying rates of political beliefs among the population, those selections would have a very high chance of selection bias. The last study in the answer doesn't talk about right-wing ideology so much as right-wing extremism. I'm not familiar with German culture, so maybe those are the same thing there? If so, that'd be something really good to clarify.

Comment: The point is that the existence of a systemic problem of right-wing extremist groups in police doesn't really say anything about how "left" or "right" the police population is as a whole. Measuring average political opinions in a population based on that population's number of extremists on either side seems like the silliest way to go about finding an answer.

Comment: There is a leftist Police Union, the Bundesarbeitsgemeinschaft kritischer Polizistinnen und Polizisten, but with only around 100 members it is not really relevant.

Comment: @der_Gottesknecht afaik it's not a union, but an association. It's great that they exist, but with 100 members and no real impact, they are indeed rather negligible (for comparison, the (at least in part) far-right dpolg has 94000 members, the center-right gdp has 190000 members).

Comment: @Clay07g A *systemic* problem of far-right extremists in the police does say a lot about their stance (as does the fact that those who may not be far-right extremists themselves are either unwilling or unable to reign in their extremist colleagues). And it's decidedly not about individual cases (hence why it's a *systemic* problem). imho my answer supports that; I wish we had even better data, but the police vehemently opposes any attempt to investigate - let alone start to resolve - the problem.

Comment: @tim If their colleagues are "unable" to reign in extremists, that still says nothing about their political views. And investigating the police's lack of ability to solve an extremist problem also wouldn't answer the question. Systemic or not, extremist problems in police populations are, at best, _tangentially_ related to the question about a population's overall distribution of political views, purely statistically speaking.

Comment: Add to it the systematic cover up of [Döner Mörd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Socialist_Underground_murders) where Turkish victims were put under suspicion (and most of the perpetrators either walked free or got away with slap on the wrist)

Comment: Could you narrow that down… a lot?

Comment: The [Bund Deutscher Kriminalbeamter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_of_German_Detectives) is a police union specifically for officers in the investigative branch. It is also somewhat linked to the SPD which you could classify as center-left. It is the smallest of the police unions so not as influential as the others but it's a police union nonetheless

Answer (score 61):

For France, the topic has covered been by a [fact-checking article](https://www.liberation.fr/checknews/2018/04/24/quelle-est-la-proportion-de-policiers-votant-a-gauche-en-france-et-de-militaires_1653591/) of a (left-leaning) newspaper, called *Libération*, published in 2018.

If you can read French, and if you know who the main figures of the different parties are, you could probably answer that police is most likely conservative there.
(Note: blue is usually associated with the right wing parties, and red, with the left wing parties.)

Briefly, the article presents several surveys conducted by well-established agencies or labs, such as [IFOP](https://www.ifop.com/en/) and [Cevipof](https://www.sciencespo.fr/cevipof/en.html).

The method is quite direct: they asked policemen who they will vote for.
The surveys include policemen, but also [Gendarmerie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Gendarmerie), a similar but somewhat distinct force, as well as the military (not related to the question).

### Question: How would you position yourself?

[image: Bar chart]
(*militaires*: military, *policiers*: police, *gauche*: left, *centre*: center, *droite*: right, *ne sait pas*: don't know)

### Question: Who will you vote for in the first round of the Presidential election (2017)?

[image: Bar chart 2]
(*extrême gauche*: far left, *Hamon + Mélanchon*: 2 heads of left wing parties, *Macron*: self-described as center, *Fil[l]on + Dupont-Aignan*: 2 heads of right wing parties, *Le Pen*: self-described as neither, but usually described as far right)

Comment: The only answer on here with directly-relevant data! Good stuff. Unfortunately the article has broken links to the actual studies so I couldn't see their specific methodologies, but the article claims that the surveys are representative. Assuming that's the case, this is pretty definitive evidence (for France).

Comment: Interestingly to note the color representation is just the reverse between the French and the US  To my knowledge, it aligns with China though. :)

Comment: @r13 Red is a classic leftist colour worldwide, the US being the odd one (again).

Comment: @zhantongz Similar to steeling wheel on the left or right, it is quite interesting to note the difference. The US can be in the minority camp on this matter, but I don't buy the claim of "being the odd one". Sorry, it is far from truth/fact.

Comment: @r13 Not sure what you are arguing about, it's interesting to note the difference, it's also interesting to note the US oddity, no? "Sorry, it is far from truth/fact." I don't know how you can be so sure, although I can't claim to know every country's political parties, but in prominent democratic countries where red/blue is used as the main scheme, to my knowledge, only in RoK and US the red is the more conservative party.

Comment: @R13 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_states_and_blue_states#Origins_of_the_color_scheme interestingly it's a newish thing, with the conventional red=left up to the 1996 election and red=republican only since 2000. (I had wondered whether it was a hang over from the early C20th when the Republican was more progressive, but that is not the case, it was just one news presenter doing it in an odd way and somehow it took hold)

Comment: @Pete Kirkham Thanks. Very informative and interesting reading.

Answer (score 36):

It seems obvious that armed forces (police, military, special services) attract more likely people who:

- Do not mind carrying and potentially using weapons;
- like to tell other people what to do;
- don't mind being told what to do;
- are not opposed to use physical coercion as a means to control behavior of others;
- support the government and the ruling order.

Being affiliated with weapons, having an autoritarian-leaning mindset and appreciating the current government are all conservative traits. Applicants for such services self-select to be conservative.

(Note that the self-labelling of a regime as  "democratic", "socialist", "communist", or even "anarchist" does not change this analysis. You'll inevitably find that even the henchmen of truly revolutionary regimes will self-select this way, which is one of the problems with revolutions.)

Naturally, this pattern is not confined to Europe or any other region but applies there as well.

One mitigation strategy for the mitlitary is to have mandatory mitlitary service which restricts this self-selection to the officer grades. For example, Germany's problem with right-wing military factions has become more virulent since conscription ended together with the Cold War.

Comment: "are not opposed to use physical coercion as a means to control behavior of others". Anyone who believes in the rule of law supports physical coercion. How else do you think laws are applied?

Comment: @DrMcCleod: In democracies, laws are usually applied by consensus. The idea that violence is needed is a characteristic of totalitarian states.

Comment: @DrMcCleod There's a spectrum there though between: "I guess, as a last resort, if you're really sure it's necessary" and "Lets go bust some heads of these law breakers!"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121007/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-reinstate-monica-are-police-in-western-european).

Comment: @MSalters “In democracies, laws are usually applied by consensus.” No they aren’t.

Comment: An "anarchist regime" sounds like a contradiction in itself - was there ever such a thing?

Comment: @DrMcCleod: The reason why the huge majority of people do not kill or rape anyone is because they simply do not want to. They don't need the threat of hell or the risk of being beaten by the police in order to do the right thing.

Comment: @EricDuminil I agree. But when people *do* break the law, they either submit to lawful authority or face proportionate violence. Those are the only options if you are to have rule of law.

Comment: @DrMcCleod Generally they face disproportionate violence, not either of those two.

Comment: @MSalters I don’t think that’s the case. When laws are broken police use violence to detain people. Then the prison system uses violence to continue to restrict people’s freedoms when convinced. Sure, it’s violence by agreement of the people, rather than violence by one person deciding it, but it is very definitely still violence.

Comment: @rob74 yes, several, though all pretty short-lived and generally unrecognised - the Makhnovites in Ukraine for one

Comment: This speculation is plausible and I agree, but it doesn't answer the question.  On your final paragraph: this appears to be why the Swedish left party supports conscription (in other countries, left parties afaik strongly oppose conscription).

Comment: Leftists: "we will use armed police to shoot you if you don't pay taxes for what we want". Also leftists: "right wing likes to use guns and force".

Answer (score 3):

Some comments expressed this but none of the answers did. So, let's add this as an asnswer:

1. The question isn't very clear on distinctions between "police as institution", "police as policemen" and "police as in police bosses/brass".

   For example, police brass (bosses) have been notoriously more left wing in many locales, as a direct consequence of the fact that they are more often than not political animals (at best, working WITH politicians, at worst, APPOINTED BY politicians) - and governments in places with more police - meaning more urban centers - are far more left wing than average for pretty much any country. Adding to this is progressive institutional capture - if you don't publicly support left wing goals (DEI, other such narratives), you face the same community/institutional pressure from activists and government as other institutions such as large corporations and colleges.

   As specific consequences (and examples to prove this), police bosses often denied facts that would lead to "inconvinient to left wing" conclusions/demands, such as crimes disproportionately committed by a "protected minority" - for example Birmingham grooming gangs, where everyone can see the evidence, but police bosses loudly protested there was no problem. Same with "police can't enter" areas in some cities - if you ask a ground policeman, you will get one answer, if you ask their ultimate police boss, you get the opposite.
2. Police in general - both individually and institutionally - have a goal of "maintaining the order". In other words, they want to reduce upset to order, especially crimes.

   Which means that police reaction to left or right wing is very likely to be predicated NOT on their politics, but on their risk to "cause problems" - meaning their tactics as well as their numbers. If a 100-member far left group stages a quiet sit-in without disturbing anyone, they are far less of a police-view "problem" than 3-member right wing group dead set on causing actual violence, but also far less of a police-view problem than 100K sized center left group - simply because 100K sized protest is a ***likely source of problems***, regardless of views professed.

   This is so strong, that it even produced a movie/fiction trope, where a policeman insists that some "good" but "looks like trouble/causing wave" character leave town; or both fictional AND REAL police frowning on vigilantes.

Answer (score 2):

Police officers (and really any individuals that serve to guard the state to some capacity such as soldiers, intelligence officers etc.) have two influences on their political leanings as a generalisation, they are more likely to be associated closely with the power structure of the state and they are more likely to take a tough on crime perspective.

Most Western governments (including Western European) generally lean conservative, and as such the power structures of these nations tend to lean conservative. When most of the commanding officers of a police force are providing orders that align with their conservative political view, then this will be reflected in the police force (fear from officers to go against accepted beliefs also comes into play here; few people want to raise their voice against the crowd).

This as well as the fact that "tough on crime" is generally a conservative approach means that the person (police officer) holding that view is more likely to be conservative. Crime is mostly conducted by disadvantaged or ill individuals, and as the only tool (generally) available to police is to punish criminals to deter them, it can be clear to see why this goes against a left-leaning approach.

One thing that interests me is in most Western nations when a strong left-leaning party comes to power the police (and army and intelligence agency) seem to often attempt to undermine said ruling party. I wonder if a left-leaning party were to be able to hold onto power for a generation in a Western nation, if police (and others) would eventually fall in line with the shifting power structures of the state and become more left-leaning?

As an example of this last point I have often remembered a shocking (from my perspective) story from Australia between the years of 1951 and 1975 or so. The centre-right party of the time in 1951 created ASIS (Australia's international intelligence agency) without informing anyone of its existence outside of this party's highest members. During this time ASIS spent a great deal of its resources creating smear campaigns against the centre-left party at the time and have been confirmed to have been involved with the secretive disappearances and arrests of left-leaning public individuals. The centre-left party only eventually found out about ASIS in 1975 (about four years after they came to power) and even after ASIS was publicly revealed to exist they still directed most of their resources to undermining the ruling party.

I always found this story interesting (and shocking) and a good reflection of all these factors I talk about.

Comment: ASIO was founded in 1949 by the then Labor (center left) government. You are probably thinking of ASIS, which was secret from the public until the 70s, but there is no suggestion that it was secret from the PM.

Comment: Has any strongly left-leaning party gained power in any western country since the Second Spanish Republic?  I'm aware that the YPG in Kurdistan/Syria wants to abolish the police, but I'm not aware of any other examples.

Comment: @Jack yes I did mean ASIS sorry (has now be corrected in OP). I often get the two mixed up. I am struggling to find clear information on exactly when Labor ministers became aware of the existence of ASIS, but it appears almost certain that they had no (confirmed) knowledge of such an organisation prior to Gough Whitlam's succession to position as PM.

Comment: @gerrit I can't think of any examples of strongly left-leaning parties in Western nations since the fall of the Second Spanish Republic, but there may be parties that are considered more than just centre-left as the status quo in the West is conservative.

Comment: @gerrit Depending on how "strong" you consider them, Syriza in Greece, and lately "Unidas Podemos" in Spain through a coalition with PSOE could qualify.

Comment: This answer is 100% provably BS. Why? Because government in most urban centers in US (and not just US) is generally hard left, and **police is not a national but local institution, especially in USA**. In other words, their immediate political bosses are FAR FAR more likely to be left wing than right wing. How right wing is Chicago police when chicago hasn't had a right wing government in 100 or 200 years? ...

Comment: ... In New York? (which hasn't had a right wing mayor in forever except Guliani for 8 years - when policing actually did take a turn for "more right" in response to crime crisis which caused Guliani to be elected in the first placec). In Washington DC which hasn't had a right wing government in decades I guess, if not more. In LA?